# Puthds Nifi 0 bytes

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

We are trying a inhouse nifi integration with SSL enabled CDH 5.13.3, but while using nifi puthdfs processor we can able to see only files with 0 bytes. what could be wrong

Comment: Where are you see 0 bytes files?  In nifi List(X), 0 byte flow files are sent to the next Processor Fetch(X) to actually get the file...

Comment: In the hdfs we are getting 0 bytes files after writing

Comment: update the original post with your flow, so we can see what you have setup upstream from PutHdfs.